# Why won't Arch recognize devices plugged into a Dell dock WD15?

Tags: arch-linux, docking-station

I have a Dell dock WD15 plugged into my laptop via USB-C cable. Two monitors are plugged into the dock, as is an Ethernet cable and a USB keyboard and a USB mouse.

I know the monitors are detected because they display output from the laptop. But the Ethernet cord, keyboard and mouse are not detected.

How do I get Arch to recognize the other devices plugged into the dock?

UPDATE WITH SOME TAIL-END OUTPUT FROM `sudo dmesg`

```
[  287.884424] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[  287.884436] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  287.884439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  287.884442] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[  291.370551] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[  291.370573] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  291.370579] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  291.370588] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[  300.365856] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[  300.365869] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  300.365871] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  300.365874] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
[  332.822344] audit: type=1101 audit(1638998292.589:137): pid=2137 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="chris" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  332.823862] audit: type=1110 audit(1638998292.589:138): pid=2137 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_env,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  332.827532] audit: type=1105 audit(1638998292.593:139): pid=2137 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  332.849507] audit: type=1106 audit(1638998292.616:140): pid=2137 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  332.849596] audit: type=1104 audit(1638998292.616:141): pid=2137 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_env,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  358.820851] audit: type=1101 audit(1638998318.594:142): pid=2163 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="chris" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  358.823123] audit: type=1110 audit(1638998318.594:143): pid=2163 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_env,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
[  358.827208] audit: type=1105 audit(1638998318.597:144): pid=2163 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/1 res=success'
```

Comment: How much *does* it detect? What do you have at the tail of `dmesg` upon plugging it in, and does `modprobe -v usbhid` succeed?

Comment: @user1686 When the USB-C is plugged into my laptop, it charges. The laptop also detects the monitors plugged into the dock. I've also updated my question with `dmesg` output. There is no output when I execute `modprobe -v usbhid`.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the dock is NOT used for connecting extra monitors (and is connected to the laptop without any monitor attached beforehand)? Have you tested whether the C port works when a C plug USB device is connected to it directly and/or when an A plug USB device is connected to it through a "simple" C-to-A adapter/hub?

Comment: (1) Try this command: `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`. (2) Is your kernel updated? (3) Please add to the post the output of `lsusb -t` (the output of `lsusb -v` might be too long) (4) Try [fwupd](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/) to see if it has any firmware updates to suggest.

Comment: Please note that this is not a Thunderbolt dock. It is just using USB-C with DisplayPort Alt Mode. // Please provide the `dmesg` output you get when plugging in the dock.

Comment: That's a typical issue of Thunderbolt security. IN Windows, you'll need to open TB Control Center - Maybe there's an equivalent in linux. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1774458/714576)

Answer (score 1):

> To ensure that your docking station is recognized by your PC and functioning optimally, please update your PC’s BIOS and your docking station’s drivers in the order provided below: [link](https://www.dell.com/support/article/SLN301970)

From the [Dell support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ed/product-support/product/dell-dock-wd15/docs)

It basically says you need to update Bios, Intel Thunderbolt 3 Firmware, Intel Thunderbolt Controller Driver, Intel HD Graphics Driver, RealTek USB GBE Ethernet Controller Driver, RealTek USB Audio Driver for the Dell Thunderbolt™ Dock and Dell Dock.
And in the end, update the firmware of your dock.

I wonder if updated drivers exist for Arch Linux, so in such situation it's possible that your dock simply won't work correctly.

I know answers should be self-contained but it seems futile to copy more than this