# Thunderbolt Dock connects only displays, won't connect USB / Ethernet

Tags: windows, laptop, thunderbolt

I bought a new Thunderbolt-Dock for my Office-Setup.

However, when I connect my laptop, only the two (4K) displays will work. The USB won't work. Nor do the Ethernet or audio connectors.

I can (almost surely) exclude hardware failures of the Dock: I thought this was the case and asked for a replacement part. But the replacement dock shows the same beaviour, so it must somehow be linked to my Laptop.

Neither Device Manager nor [USB TreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) show the dock as connected: it looks like driver installation is not being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [security reasons](https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Demystifying-Thunderbolt-3-Security-Levels/td-p/7529712), **connecting Thunderbolt devices need approval from the user**, although the OS might not prompt for this. (see also the EDIT below).

1. click on the search icon in the taskbar, and type "Thunderbolt"
2. Open the "Thunderbolt Control Center"
3. From the menu, select "Approve Devices"
4. You should now see your Docking station listed. From the dropdown, choose "Always connect".
5. Your Laptop will now automatically connect to the Dock, everytime it gets connected.

[image]

### EDIT

There's also the possibility to change the [Thunderbolt Security Level](https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Demystifying-Thunderbolt-3-Security-Levels/td-p/7529712) in BIOS, in order to skip the above step. Since Thunderbolt uses the PCIe interface, a connected TB device can have direct access to system memory: this is a potential security issue, so read the linked article if in doubt.

In BIOS, you should be able to find the settings in Advanced -> Thunderbolt -> Thunderbolt Security Level. If you don't have any security concerns, set it to SL0, and any TB device will always connect.